# Javascript does not throw a 'not defined' error when line ends in a colon

Tags: javascript

I spotted this mistake in a JS function, where a url was intended to be a comment, but the slashes were omitted... strangely no JS error is thrown? Why does a line that ends in a colon not produce an `... is not defined` error?

```
function test() {
    https://www.test.com
    console.log('success');
}
test();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colon is creating a label called "https". See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

> The labeled statement can be used with break or continue statements. It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.

It can be used with `break` and `continue` keywords to specify which loop should be `break`ed out of or `continue`d from:

```
loop1:
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    loop2:
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (someCondition) {
            continue loop1; // continue the outer loop rather than the inner loop
        }
   }
}
```